# AS3 variable length argument expand to call another function with var length args

Tags: actionscript-3

how to do this

```
function foo(x:*, ...args):* {
}

function bar(x:*, ...args):* {
   foo(x, args); // how to expand args ? the args is an array now
}
```

how to expand args ? when I call `bar(1,2,3)`, I wish it call `foo(1,2,3)`, but it call `foo(1,[2,3])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function bar(x:*, ...args):* {
   args.unshift( x ); //add x to the front of the args array
   foo.apply( <scope>, args );
}
```

If `foo` and `bar` are declared in the same class `<scope>` should be `this`, otherwise it should be the instance of the class declaring `foo` and if `foo` is a global function it should be `null`

```
foo.apply( this, args );
//-- or --
foo.apply( myFooInstance, args );
//-- or --
foo.apply( null, args );
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this partially answers your question:
http://www.flex888.com/574/can-i-have-a-variable-number-of-arguments-in-as3.html

However, I don't think it's possible to do exactly what you're requesting in any sort of reasonable way.