# Weird behavior of Red5 service parameters called from Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, red5

I have a Red5 service function that receives a single string as a parameter, and another function that takes no parameters, like the code below:

```
public class AService
{
   private String someName;

   public void setName(String aName)
   {
       someName = aName;
   }
   .
   .
   public String makeMessage()
   {
       return("Hello, "+someName);
   }
   .
   .
   other functions
}
```

I also have an ActionScript function that calls the service function, using the dynamic parameter:

```
public class Connector
{
   private var netConn: NetConnection;

   public function invokeCall(theFunc:String,...theParams): void
   {
      var resp:Responder = new Responder(checkResult);
      netConn.call(theFunc,resp,theParams);
   }
   .
   .
}
```

I am aware that the "...theParams" is actually an array of parameter objects. I also know that the NetConnector class' call() method uses that parameter object array. Unfortunately, when I do an invokeCall() on my service's makeMessage() method (without putting in a parameter) like so:

```
invokeCall("AService.makeMethod");
```

I get a function nonexistent message from Red5. The only way I can make it work is to create two invoke methods, one with parameters and one without, and call that function without parameters.

Furthermore, calling my setName() function, like so:

```
invokeCallwithPrams("AService.setName","factor3");
```

doesn't seem to work unless I change the signature of my service function:

```
public class AService
{
   private String someName;

   public void setName(String[] aName)
   {
       someName = aName[0];
   }
   .
   .
   public String makeMessage()
   {
       return("Hello, "+someName);
   }
   .
   .
   other functions
}
```

which I don't mind (even though the Red5 documentation indicates that I shouldn't have to treat the parameter as an array), except that when I pass the string "factor3" into the NetConnection class' call() method, somehow it becomes "[factor3]" in setName()!

Obviously, something is screwy here, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I am using Red5 Version 1.0.1 and my Actionscript is Version 3.

Can anyone explain to me what is going on and (more importantly) how to fix this???

If so, please advise...

UPDATE: The weirdness continues

I did a test in which I changed the parameter of the function I used to set up and invoke the NetConnection class' call() method. Instead of passing it a "...theParams", I changed it to theParams:String, like so:

```
   public function invokeCall(theFunc:String,theParams:String): void
   {
      var resp:Responder = new Responder(checkResult);
      netConn.call(theFunc,resp,theParams);
   }
```

Interestingly, the brackets that appear in my service method setName() go away!

Whatever this problem is, it has something to do with the dynamic parameters in Actionscript. I suspect that I have found a bug in Actionscript 3 that does not allow it to properly handle dynamic parameters that are passed to a method from another method.

Has anyone else seen this problem? Is there any solution? The dynamic parameters are supposed to allow anyone to add parameters as necessary and make them any object that is necessary. Unfortunately, it doesn't look like you can use dynamic parameters passed from another method without them being screwed up.

This looks like a serious bug in Actionscript. Am I correct?

Someone please advise...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It is not a bug in Actionscript, it is a bit of strangeness in the language.

The basic information about the solution can be found here:

[AS3 variable length argument expand to call another function with var length args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600344/as3-variable-length-argument-expand-to-call-another-function-with-var-length-arg)

Based on what is there, I needed to do the following in the method I am using for invokeCallwithParams:

```
.
.
var conn:Connector = new Connector();

private function invokeCaller(fName:String,...cParams)
{
   cParams.unshift(fName);
   conn.invokeCall.apply(conn,cParams);
}
```

This eliminates the unnecessary brackets passed into my setName() service function, meaning that I can pass dynamic, variable length parameters from one method to another...